# Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Despite it's correctly set

Tags: android, cordova, ionic4

When i run

> $ionic cordova build android

build failed with this error :

> cordova build android
> Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it >manually.
> Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' >to include path to valid SDK directory.
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

Despite when i run :

> cordova requirements

I get this results :

> Requirements check results for android:
>
> Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
>
> Android SDK: installed true
>
> Android target: installed android-29,android-28,android-27,android->26,android-25,android-24,android-23,android-22,android-21
>
> Gradle: installed /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle

EDIT : i'm using Ubuntu

EDIT : SOLVED BY running SUDO -E ionic cordova build android

Answer (score 2):

Type these commands in the console -

> export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk (Your SDK path)
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

To make it permanent for the current user, add it to the **~/.bashrc** file (open it in terminal through vim ~/.bashrc)

Answer (score 1):

Your environmental variables are set up incorrectly. Go on your windows/mac search and look up 'environmental variables'. Click edit environmental verifiable then click 'environmental verifiable' then add ANDROID_HOME like so

[image]

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu , any idea how to do the same ?